# Python If message contains

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Below code if we type `!message` command bot asks message, when we type messsage it converts to Embed.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def message(self, ctx):
    message = await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "What you want to Send? ")
    reply = await self.bot.wait_for_message(timeout= 60, author=ctx.message.author, channel=ctx.message.channel)

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Something goes here", description="{}".format(reply.content), color=0x029F98)
    await self.bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, embed=embed)
```

But in my `on_message` i have `message.content = message.content.lower()` which converts to lower. So i added a line to ignore if bot message contains a specific line ignore lower case.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "Something goes here" not in message.content:
        message.content = message.content.lower()

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

So how to make ignore lower case if bot message have some words.

Comment: Can you please add the expected input and output in the sample code, and show us what is not working?

Comment: Yes that I understood but what is not working? can you show some example of values of message.content and word you want to filter based on?

Comment: how are you adding another word? You might need to chain conditionals here to achieve this, i.e.

`if "Something goes here" not in message.content or if "something else" not in message.content `

Comment: @Demotry I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve still, can't you just change the line to this?

`if "Something goes here" not in message.content or if "Something goes here" in message.content:`

Comment: @Liam  I tried that getting invalid syntax so  i changed that line to `if "Something goes here 1" not in message.content or "Something goes here 2" in message.content:`  by removing `if` after `or`   now it ignores for lower case for `Something goes here 1` and not for `Something goes here 2`

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the second if in my statement, will edit that as it shouldn't be there. This worked fine for me:

`>>> message = "blah"
>>> if "test" not in message or "test in message":
...     print("Hi")
... 
Hi
`

You need to bear in mind that string matching is literal, meaning that it might be easier to convert the message to lower and the text that you are looking for so something like:

`if "Something goes here".lower() not in message.content.lower():`

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to ignore **ANY** message matching `something goes here`, then just use this code:

```
if "something goes here" not in message.content.lower():    
    # do >something
```